# How to set equal height to neighbours divs using aungularjs?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my code: **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3pay2yc)**

At start my panels are hidden and then after button click I want to show every panel with equal height (I want to streche panel-body).
Thank you so much for help!

```
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.isActive = false;

  $scope.toogle = function () {
    $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **Flexbox** instead of `col`'s it's the best solution, check the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3pay2yc/3/).

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to set `height` for your panels -

```
.panel {
    min-height: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```